# Best practice to design fact table rollups for BI's Aggregate Navigation

Tags: database-design, powerbi, olap, datamart

I am trying to implement fact table and its rollups the right way, to be able one day to transfer it to some BI system

And, based on [Oracle's article](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIEMG/GUID-9D228A99-DFF4-4400-89B4-6A18DB5CD3BD.htm) and [KimballGoups's article](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/aggregate-fact-table-cube/), as I understand, whole design must obey strict principles

So, suppose there is a table `fact_sales`:

```
-----------------------------------------
| dim_store | dim_product | total_sales |
-----------------------------------------
|         1 |           1 |          10 |
|         1 |           2 |          20 |
|         2 |           3 |          20 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Suppose, there is a need to make another table, rolled up by store, omitting product column, so, it'll look like this, `fact_sales_by_store`:

```
---------------------------
| dim_store | total_sales |
---------------------------
|         1 |          30 |
|         2 |          20 |
---------------------------
```

And, as I guess, things are not that simple, and to make BI's Aggregate Navigation work properly, there must be some trick in dimensions, but I can not get it from articles

As I see/guess, beetween dims and fact table must be some "Logical Table Source", or some hierarchy dims?

Can you please point me further based on that example?) Big thx

Comment: I'm not a PowerBI expert but as no-one else has responded in the last 24 hours I'll give it a go... As far as I'm aware, if you create an aggregate table within PowerBI then it will enable Aggregate Navigation. However, if you already have aggregate tables in your external source and want to use them directly then you can't use Aggregate Navigation but you can use DAX to determine which fact table to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any modern BI app (e.g. Power BI), I would not create aggregate tables at all. The BI app used should be capable of aggregating data flexibly, by any combination of dimensions.

There might be more complex requirements than what you outlined, that justify creating two fact tables with differing grain/granularity.  In that scenario, a capable BI tool can pull together aggregates from two fact tables for a single output dataset/visual.  The unifying factor would be any common dimension tables.

Comment: Aggregate tables are created for performance reasons, not because BI tools cannot create aggregates

Comment: Well they used to, but are no longer needed with apps like Power BI. Aggregation using its Vertipac (columnstore) architecture will almost always outperform SQL aggregations.  Both the articles linked by the OP are 5+ years old. Kimble Group closed in 2015.